# Adding a custom Artisan command with Behat

Tags: php, laravel-4, behat

I've registered a custom Artisan command:

```
Artisan::add(new MigrateAll);
```

The class resides in app/commands (default location)

However when I run Behat I get the error: 
    `Class 'MigrateAll' not found`

Artisan is called in Behat for setting up the DB:

```
/**
* @static
* @beforeSuite
*/
public static function setUpDb()
{

    Artisan::call('migrate:install');
//...
}
```

Do I need to give it a namespace? (I could not find the correct way to call the Artisan::add command with a namespaced class)

Comment: Have you tried giving it a namespace?

Comment: Can you add more information on where you've registered it and when the error occurs?

Comment: @IanBytchek added info - the error occurs when I run behat.

Comment: You wouldn't use Behat tag otherwise, I'm certain. It's hard to get the picture of what's going on without roughly knowing the code structure and what you are trying to achieve. I assume you use this for bootstrapping? If so, can you share the whole bootstrap code? When and where is it called? On some hook, in some step, or elsewhere?

Comment: @IanBytchek the only place it's called is in app/start/artisan.php. I am also using Artisan calls in Behat. But currently not this command. Which is perhaps why its falling over..? Will update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat related to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609579/behat-3-and-laravel-testing-environment-not-being-honoured). Your Behat test suite runs in a separate process independently of your app and knows nothing about the configuration. This also applies to the autoloading in your bootstrap and the autoloading would be the most likely reason why classes don't get found. This should be easily fixed by using Composer to autoload your own sources and vendor packages (both in your app and in your test suite).

```
# composer.json
{

    "require": {
        "…": "…"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "../src"
        }
    }
}

// Include composer's autoloader in your `setUp()` / bootstrap / index.php.

include __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Take that process separation as a rule and keep in mind that Laravel like any other framework requires a whole bunch of other configuration. Since you are trying to use the database component, your next issue will be with that, because it won't be configured in your test suite.

The best approach is to create separate bootstrap file for Behat, which would inherit most lines from your normal bootstrap, where you need to pass the necessary configuration and do this:

```
/**
 * @static
 * @beforeSuite
 */
public static function setUp()
{
    include_once('bootstrap.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configured your behat environment with [this tut (Laravel, BDD And You: Let’s Get Started)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-bdd-and-you-lets-get-started--cms-22155), after you added a new command, you need to `$ composer dump-autoload` to make behat to know the command.